# GatherBy using Conditional bins

Tags: list-manipulation

If I had a dataset such as:

```
s={{1,1.1,1},{2,1.2,2},{1,2.3,1},{3,2.2,2},{1,3.5,1},{4,3.6,2},{1,4.2,3},{2,4.4,1}}
```

I want to gather sublists based on the 2nd term of each sublist, such that first group has 2nd term of each sublists between 0 and 2, the second group has 2nd term of each sublists between 2 and 3.7, the third group has 2nd term of each sublists between 3.7 and 5. My output should look like this:

```
output:= {{{1,1.1,1},{2,1.2,2}},{{1,2.3,1},{3,2.2,2},{1,3.5,1},{4,3.6,2}},{{1,4.2,3},{2,4.4,1}}}
```

I suspect it should be something of the sort:

```
r = {0, 2, 3.7, 5};
GatherBy[s, {#[[2]] > #1 &, #[[2]] < #2}] & /@ MapThread[Most@r, Rest@r]
```

Comment: I mean, `GatherBy[s, #[[2]] < 2.5 &]` does what you want. Can you provide an example for which that fails so that we have a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: if there are more than 2 groups, then I need to define more conditions.

Comment: @brama it is a different question then.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/120696/121

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50559/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your division markers,

```
divisions = {2, 3.7, 5}
```

Then use `GatherBy` and use the sorted position of an element in this list as the gathering function

```
GatherBy[s, Position[Sort[Append[divisions, #[[2]]]], #[[2]]] &]


(* {{{1, 1.1, 1}, {2, 1.2, 2}}, {{1, 2.3, 1}, {3, 2.2, 2}, {1, 
       3.5, 1}, {4, 3.6, 2}}, {{1, 4.2, 3}, {2, 4.4, 1}}} *)
```

Comment: Also `GatherBy[s, First@Ordering@Ordering@Prepend[r, #[[2]]] &]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
ineqFu[a_, b_, max_, expr_, data_] :=
 If[
  a == 0,
  expr <= data[[b]]
  ,
  If[
   b == max,
   data[[a]] < expr
   ,
   data[[a]] < expr <= data[[b]]
   ]
  ]

max = Length@bounds + 1;
tokenizedIneqs = 
  ineqFu[##, max, token, r] & @@@ 
   Partition[Range[0, max], 2, 1];
funkyTown =
  Which @@@
   (Function@
      Evaluate[Riffle[tokenizedIneqs, Range[max]]] /. 
     token :> #[[2]]);
result = GatherBy[s, funkyTown];
```

We then have

```
result === output
```

> True

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but what I meant by my earlier comment is that if the dataset were larger and if there are multiple values for the #[[2]] (such that the bins are 0 to 2.5, 2.5 to 4.5, 4.5 to 6.2, 6.2 to 7.4, and so on), how can I gather for the above bins? so my solution will be {{{x11,1.1,y11},{x21,2,y21},...{xn1,2.4,yn1}},{{x12,2.6,y12},{x22,2.8,y22},...{xn2,4.4,yn2}},..{{x1m,6.3,y1m},{x2m,6.8,y2m},...{xnm,7.3,ynm}}}

Comment: @brama If I understand you correctly (big if), then my code does what you ask. Note that the my variable `result` stores the result/output/solution, the reason I show the output of `result[[All,All,2]]` instead is because it is easier for me to see from this that the code works.

Comment: I am not afraid that's not what I want. Please see the edited question. Hope it is clearer.

Comment: @brama I hope I did not confuse you earlier by slightly adapting the input (`data`/`s`). But without adapting my code, the `result` of my code equals the desired `output`.

Comment: @brama I see that you have edited your data (`s`), but you have not made your `output` correspond to this yet. I mean there is a `1` in output that should be a `1.2`.

Comment: Yes. I missed it in the output. my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = {{1, 1.1, 1}, {2, 1.2, 2}, {1, 2.3, 1}, {3, 2.2, 2}, {1, 3.5, 1}, {4, 3.6, 2}, {1, 4.2, 3}, {2, 4.4, 1}};
divisions = {2, 3.7, 5};

condGather[list_, divi_] := 
 Block[{second, f, s = list, divisions = divi, els, ord},
  second := #[[2]] &;
  f[x_] := Block[{divs, part, int, cond, which},
    divs = Insert[Insert[divisions, -Infinity, 1], Infinity, -1];
    part = Partition[divs, 2, 1];
    int = IntervalMemberQ[#1, x] & /@ Interval /@ part;
    cond = Riffle[int, Range[Length@divs - 1]];
    which = Which[##] & @@ cond
    ];
  els = f /@ second /@ s;
  ord = Length /@ SplitBy[els, Max];
  FoldPairList[TakeDrop, s, ord]
  ]

condGather[s, divisions]
```

> {{{1, 1.1, 1}, {2, 1.2, 2}}, {{1, 2.3, 1}, {3, 2.2, 2}, {1, 3.5, 
>      1}, {4, 3.6, 2}}, {{1, 4.2, 3}, {2, 4.4, 1}}}

```
TableForm[%, TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image]